# Is there a way to have a Ubuntu server automatically restart a NPM process if it fails?

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, npm

I am running a Discord bot on AWS. Is it possible to have AWS redo `npm start` if for whatever reason the process stops running?

I couldn't find anything like this on AWS help center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something like [PM2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2) should help you out.

From their description:

PM2 is a production process manager for Node.js applications with a built-in load balancer. It allows you to keep applications alive forever, to reload them without downtime and to facilitate common system admin tasks.

Comment: Usage examples and tips about PM2 can be found in the answer I posted in the linked question.